# Тире или не тире - вот, в чем вопрос.

Tags: пунктуация

У нас на работе дел - завались.
Нужно ли тире в этом случае, а если нет, но какой знак?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, тире тут можно поставить, чтобы сделать акцент на слове "завались", но, если такой задачи не стоит, можно обойтись и без него.